# Local IIS in Windows 10 can be accessed using 127.0.0.1 and localhost, but not by mean of its IP

Tags: iis, bindings

I have a notebook with Windows 10.

I have installed IIS, then,I have tried to browse, using a browser in the same notebook, to URL 127.0.0.1, it shows default web site. Then, I used localhost, and the same, it shows default web site. However, I used its IP, and the site delays a time and then it shows the message:

> This site cannot be accessed
>
> IP delays too much to reply.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT

(sorry if the above text is not exact as the messages in English version of Windows. I have Spanish version)

Bindings of the default web site is set to "all assigned ip". I tried by explicitly set that combobox to its IP, but the same problem happens.

How can I solve it?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Have u done port forward in ur router?

Comment: That is not my router... it is the router somewhere in this company. However, I don't think it is router problem (I am not completely sure) because I can browse default web site in other server.

Comment: Cant browse via ip, you mean public ip? Or anothwr local ip?

Comment: Show the output of `ipconfig` at command prompt, as well as your site binding.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no reason to try to access the website on your local machine from your own machine using the machine's IP address.

You're trying to troubleshoot something that won't ever happen on its own.

Reference the site by DNS name (you can use your c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file to define this if you don't have an internal DNS server), use 'localhost' as you already said works.